ASP.NET integration test breaks when exception thrown, despite GlobalExceptionHandler handles it
The context
I implemented integration tests for my ASP.NET backend, followed this article.
Implemented several tests which successfully run.
I have a GlobalExceptionHandler which modify response when a specific exception has been thrown.
Tested all of my endpoints with Postman, also the use-cases when the GlobalExceptionHandler handles exceptions and modifies result and worked perfectly.
The problem
When I implement a test case where I expect the GlobalExceptionHandler modifies the response(StatusCode and writes ResponseBody), the test dies with UnhandledException, despite my GlobalExceptionHandler handles it.
Question
Has anyone encountered this problem? How could I handle this integration test case scenario?

Can you debug the test and verify the code that adds the GlobalExceptionHandler is called?

Of course, I already did that. There is the TryHandleAsync of the ExceptionHandler, which returns true, which means the exception is handled. After this, the test dies with Unhandled exception.
